# element in span with ng-bind not displayed

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind

Here my problem.

```
<span class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" ng-bind-template="{{controller.getToolTip()}}">
   <span class="icon " ng-class="controller.getIcone()" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

In my controller, `getToolTip()` returns a string and same for `getIcone()`.
The second span is never displayed and not present in the DOM.

But if i replace by this :

```
<span class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
   {{controller.getToolTip()}}
   <span class="icon " ng-class="controller.getIcone()" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

This time i can see my second span. Do you have an idea what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-template` directive replaces the element's content with the interpolation of the template in the ngBindTemplate attribute.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate

There is also a syntax error in the sample template. Quotes don't close and curly braces are needed in that case, like this:

```
<span class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" ng-bind-template="{{controller.getToolTip()}}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes you're right. I try different things and i made a mistake in my post. So, the only way to display the second span is to use interpolation instead of ng-bind-template (or ng-bind) ?

Comment: You can always follow another approach using a custom directive. ng-bind and ng-bind-template both replace the content